# Down casting HKWorkout to my custom class

Tags: ios, swift, casting, healthkit

With Swift 4.0, I am trying to do a down cast between the built-in HealhKit class HKWorkout to my own custom class. My class inherits from HKWorkout. HKWorkout inherits from HKSample. Down casting to HKWorkout from HKSample works. So then why can't I further cast this to my own class? I'd like to perform the cast without explicitly looping over an array of samples if possible. The reason for my custom class is to store addl properties and methods.

```
//This works. Note I am not explicitly looping over samples array.
//samples is an array of HKSample objects.
let workouts:[HKWorkout] = samples as! [HKWorkout]

//Does not work. FRWorkout is my class, inherits from HKWorkout.
let workouts:[FRWorkout] = samples as! [FRWorkout]
```

The end goal is to get an array of FRWorkout objects instead of HHWorkout objects.

Below is complete context:

```
class FRWorkout: HKWorkout {
    var customProperty:UInt = 0

}

let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate,
                                              ascending: false)

        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKObjectType.workoutType(),
                                  predicate: nil,
                                  limit: 50,
                                  sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in

                                    //Here I want FRWorkout objects instead of HKWorkout. I need to add addl info to the HKWorkout. How can this be achieved?
                                    guard let workouts = samples as? [HKWorkout], error == nil else {
                                            completion(nil, error)
                                            return
                                    }

}
```

Comment: Where does `samples` come from?  Where/how is it declared? Since HKSample inherits from HKWorkout, you can cast to HKWorkout. FRWorkout does not inherit from HKSample so you cannot cast between those classes. Also, it is risky to force downcast from a superclass to a subclass unless you know for certain that the object actually is an instance of the subclass; a force downcast from an instance of HKWorkout to FRWorkout will crash

Comment: samples is coming from an HKQuery: `let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate,
                                              ascending: false)
        
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKObjectType.workoutType(),
                                  predicate: nil,
                                  limit: 50,
                                  sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in {  //access samples here }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HKSampleQuery` will return instances of `HKWorkout` since you are specifying `HKObjectType.workoutType()` as the `sampleType`.

You cannot get `HKSampleQuery` to return instances of `FRWorkout` since the HealthKit framework doesn't know anything about your subclass.

Even though you have declared your class, `FRWorkout` to be a subclass of `HKWorkout`, you are not receiving instances of `FRWorkout` from `HKSampleQuery` so you cannot downcast the returned objects.

As @KaneChehire pointed out, subclassing HRWorkout isn't the right approach in any case.

Comment: Ok. I solved my problem by using a struct as a wrapper to hold my addl info and the workout object. `public struct WorkoutWrapper {
    public var workout:HKWorkout!
    public var myCustomCounter:UInt = 0
}`

Comment: Why not just use the custom keys that HKWorkout already supports? Don't reinvent the wheel :) Have a look at the docs I've linked to in my answer

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs, subclassing isn't advised, so might be a good idea to explore alternatives before you go much further. [From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkout):

> Like many HealthKit classes, the HKWorkout class should not be
>   subclassed. You may extend workouts by adding metadata with custom
>   keys as appropriate for your app. For more information, see the
>   methods
>   init(activityType:start:end:duration:totalEnergyBurned:totalDistance:metadata:)
>   and
>   init(activityType:start:end:workoutEvents:totalEnergyBurned:totalDistance:metadata:).